# count all lines between a multiline comment with c++

Tags: c++, file, parsing

I am making a program where I can count comments of every programming project in any language, but I have a problem in lines counting when I want to count multiline comments like this:

```
/* this is 
  a multiline
  comment */
```

or the Ruby way:

```
=begin 
this is multiline
comment
=end
```

I can't figure out a way to count every line in a multiline comment
this is my piece of code:

```
while(getline(file_f,line)) {

    lines_count++;

    if((line.empty()))
        blanklines_count++;

    if(((line.find("//")) != string::npos) || (line.find("/*") != string::npos)) 
        comments++;
```

I didn't find something useful in other post about my problem with getline implementation , is there any solution?

Comment: Do you need to be able to skip comment sequences inside text strings? That needs a lot of additional parsing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set up some `bool` flag variable that will be set to `true` when you enter a comment, and set to `false` when you leave one.

```
// it's better to short-circuit the std::string::find
// (don't look for the start of the multi-line comment if you're already in one)
if(!inComment && line.find("//*") != std::string::npos)
    inComment = true; // don't increment here, just set the flag

if(inComment || line.find("//")) != std::string::npos)
    comments++;

if(inComment && line.find("*//") != std::string::npos)
    inComment = false;
```

Comment: (n.m. my previous comment!) How would you propose to handle `//` lines? You cannot easily check for an exit condition with those.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot it inside the condition. Maybe you can OR it with `inComment` inside the `if()`.

Comment: I'm glad. If you're wondering why incrementing is being done before checking for the end of the multiline comment, it's so `/* comment */` yields `1`, not `0` like it would do if it was being done afterwards.

Comment: @Ro Stel This actually does not work correctly if one multi-line comment ends and then another begins on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

You want to flag when you're in a multi-line comment, something like:

```
bool in_multi_line_comment = false;

// ...

while//...

    // ...
    if (!in_multi_line_comment && line.find("/*") != string::npos)
        in_multi_line_comment = true;

    if (in_multi_line_comment || line.find("//")) != std::string::npos)
        comments++;

    if (in_multi_line_comment && line.find("*/") != string::npos)
        in_multi_line_comment = false;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a Boolean variable which tells you if you are inside a multiline comment. Lets call it `is_inside_mcomment`

- when you find the multiline comment beging mark (e.g. `/*')

  ```
  is_inside_comment = true
  ```
- when you find the multiline comment end mark (e.g. '*/')

  ```
  is_inside_comment = true
  ```

for each line

- `if is_inside_mcomment comments++`

Depending on how complex and accurate you want your program to be you have to account for special cases: (e.g. multiple multiline comments on the same line, marks inside strings etc)

Answer (score 2):

You need a parser that's actually stateful and aware of input.

> **E.g.** you don't want to parse `/*` as the start of a block comment in c++ if it appears here:
>
> ```
> std::cout << "Hello /*interesting*/ world!\n";
> ```

Short of that, here's a quick demo of rolling the minimal parsers for the task you outlined in the question, using Boost Spirit:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7ed702dd79b23051)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/repository/include/qi_seek.hpp>
#include <limits>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace qr = boost::spirit::repository::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::vector<std::string> args(argv+1, argv+argc);
    if (args.empty())
        args.push_back("cpp");

    size_t comment_lines = 0;
    auto incr = px::ref(comment_lines)++;

    using It = boost::spirit::istream_iterator;
    qi::rule<It> rule;
    {
        using namespace qi;
        if (args.front() == "cpp")
            rule = qr::seek["/*"] >> ((*(char_ - eol - "*/")) [incr] % eol);
        else if (args.front() == "ruby")
            rule = qr::seek["\n=begin"] >> *(char_ - eol) % (eol - (eol >> "=end")) [incr];
        else
            rule = eps(false); // just fail
    }

    if (qi::parse(It(std::cin >> std::noskipws), {}, rule)) {
        std::cout << comment_lines << " lines in " << args.front() << " comments\n";
    } else {
        std::cout << "Couldn't parse " << args.front() << " input\n";
    }
}
```

When run for you sample input, using

```
for lang in cpp ruby java; do ./a.out $lang input.txt; done
```

You'll get the outputs:

```
3 lines in cpp comments
2 lines in ruby comments
Couldn't parse java input
```

Comment: It works and it does exactly what I want, but the compilation times is slow (it's ok I think is not a  big problem) and also I need to learn the boost library , how to use it with separate project files, but thank you anyway. I am looking now to modify this code in my needs !